# Past progressive vs Simple past

Tags: passive-voice, progressive-aspect

> Parents of young children say kids **are being left** behind as updated Covid-19 vaccines roll out.
> https://edition.cnn.com/2023/10/03/health/pediatric-covid-vaccines-rollout/index.html

1. Why use the passive progressive form, as opposed to simply "kids **are left** behind"?  Is the idea that the kids are gradually left behind or that they are currently left behind？
2. If both forms work for the sentence above, does that mean in the following question, both C and D are fine？

> Though _ behind and feeling awkward, Jack kept on running until he reached the finishing line.
> A. leaving  B. having left  **C.    left    D. being left**

Comment: The continuous form adds ***immediacy*** - emphasizing that this is an ***urgent ongoing problem.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the past progressive is used to describe an ongoing activity ([here's a link to an explanation](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_progressive_tense.htm)) where as the simple past is about an action that has been completed. The phrase "are being left behind" implies that the leaving behind is gradual and possibly increasing through the events in the latter part of the sentence.

### Your first example

In the case of the vaccines, the article is saying that children are somewhat left behind (or excluded from updated immunity) now, AND that the gap between availability for adults and for children is increasing in the future, as more vaccines are created.

### Your second example

You're right, both C (left) and D (being left) behind are acceptable, but have slightly different meaning.

- *"Though left behind and feeling awkward, Jack kept on running until he reached the finishing line."* means that Jack has already been left behind, and that the gap is no longer increasing. That it happened previously and then stayed stable through while he ran the rest of the race.
- *"Though being left behind and feeling awkward, Jack kept on running until he reached the finishing line."* means that Jack was left behind some amount earlier in the race but that that gap continues to increase throughout the race, until he reaches the finish line.

Answer (score 0):

> 1a) Why use the passive progressive form, as opposed to simply "kids are left behind"?

In general, progressive forms refer to something happening now, temporarily, whereas simple present refers to something that happens from time to time, or on a regular basis.

The time of this sentence is "*as updated Covid-19 vaccines roll out*", so it's *happening right now*, temporarily, and not in general, so simple present cannot apply.

> 1b) Is the idea that the kids are gradually left behind or that they are currently left behind?

The idea of the sentence is that the kids are currently being left behind. The grammar doesn't indicate whether it's gradual or not. It could mean either that different kids are being fully dropped behind on a regular basis, or that all kids are gradually dropping behind. It's ambiguous on that point.

> 2. If both forms work for the sentence above, does that mean in the following question, both C and D are fine?

In Jack's context, both forms *do work*, even though in the sentence above both forms don't work. The reason is, nothing in the context tells us whether Jack had already been fully dropped, or whether he was gradually being dropped. In other words, the context doesn't have enough information to determine what that sentence means and choose C or D as the correct answer.